# How to calculate covariance Matrix with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, covariance

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate a covariance matrix with Pandas.
I'm not a data scientist or a finance guy, i'm just a regular dev going a out of his league.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(252, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
print(df.cov())
```

So, if I do this, I get that kind of output:

[image]

I find that the number are huge, and i was expecting  them to be closer to zero. Do i have to calculate the return before getting the cov ?

Does anyone familiar with this could explain this a little bit or point me to a good link with explanation ? I couldn't find any link to Covariance Matrix For Dummies.

Regards,
Julien

Comment: hey mate, looks like you need to better understand cov, a great link/explanation wld be http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18058/how-would-you-explain-covariance-to-someone-who-understands-only-the-mean

Comment: what you might be looking for is correlation (which wld vary from -1 to 1) but thats a whole different thing

Comment: Use `df.corr` for correlation which was mentioned by @epattaro

Answer (score 4):

**Covariance** is a measure of the degree to which returns on two assets (or any two vector or array) move in tandem. A positive covariance means that asset returns move together, while a negative covariance means returns move inversely.

On the other side we have:

The **correlation coefficient** is a measure that determines the degree to which two variables' movements are associated. Note that the correlation coefficient measures **linear relationship** between two arrays/vector/asset.

So, portfolio managers try to reduce covariance between two assets and keep the correlation coefficient negative to have enough diversification in the portfolio. Meaning that a decrease in one asset's return will not cause a decrease in return of the second asset(That's why we need negative correlation).

Maybe you meant correlation coefficient close to zero, not covariance.

Comment: There are a few type of correlations---Pearson measures linear correlation but, Spearman measure monotonic relationships between two variables. Variables that are monotonic will share a relationship but might stagnate at some value. When the relationship between the variables is non linear, there are outliers and the distribution of values is not normal, you might consider Spearman. It will show a relationship if it exists and the p-value will show how strong the relation is with respect to the null hypothesis. Just saying that correlation is not always linear.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you haven't provided a seed for your randomly generated numbers makes th reproducibility of your experiment difficoult. However, I tried the code you are providing here and the closer covariance matrix I get is this one :

[image: covariance matrix]

To understand why the numbers in your cov_matrix are so huge you should first understand what is a covarance matrix. The covariance matrix is is a matrix that has as elements in the i, j position the the covariance between the i-th and j-th elements of a random vector.

A good link you might check is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix . Also understanding the correlation matrix might help  : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence#Correlation_matrices